# Error en JSF, error en el <p:commandButton>

Tags: jsf

```
                <h:form id="form">
                    <p:dataTable id="tblUB" var="infoUT" value="#{sdiacMB.listaUbicacionTecnica}" 
                                 resizableColumns="true" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" >
                        <p:column headerText="ID">
                            <h:outputText value="#{infoUT.idUbicacionTecnica}" />
                        </p:column>                            
                        <p:column headerText="Lugar">
                            <h:outputText value="#{infoUT.tipoLugar}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Ubicación">
                            <h:outputText value="#{infoUT.ubicacion}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Denominacion">
                            <h:outputText value="#{infoUT.denominacion}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                            <p:commandButton update=":form:utDetail" oncomplete="PF('utDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{infoUT}" target="#{sdiacMB.selectedUbicacionTecnica}" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:column>

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:commandButton value="Modificar" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>

                    <p:dialog header="Ubicacion Tecnica" widgetVar="utDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
                        <p:outputPanel id="utDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" rendered="#{not empty sdiacMB.selectedUbicacionTecnica}"  columnClasses="label,value">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Datos Ubicacion Tecnica" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="Lugar:" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{sdiacMB.selectedUbicacionTecnica.tipoLugar}" />
                                <h:outputText value="Ubicacion" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{sdiacMB.selectedUbicacionTecnica.ubicacion}" />
                                <h:outputText value="Denominacion" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{sdiacMB.selectedUbicacionTecnica.denominacion}" />
                                <h:outputText value="ID" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{sdiacMB.selectedUbicacionTecnica.idUbicacionTecnica}" />
                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:dialog>

                </h:form>
```

@ManagedBean(name="sdiacMB")
@ViewScoped
public class SistemaDeInventarioACManagedBean {

```
private UbicacionTecnicaDTO ubicacionTecnicaDTO;
private List<UbicacionTecnicaDTO> listaUbicacionTecnica;

@EJB
private IUbicacionTecnicaService ubicacionTecnicaService;

private UbicacionTecnicaDTO selectedUbicacionTecnica ;

public SistemaDeInventarioACManagedBean() {
    ubicacionTecnicaDTO = new UbicacionTecnicaDTO();
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    ListarUbicacionTecnica();        
}

public void ListarCentroDeCosto() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        listaCentroDeCosto = centroDeCostoService.listarCentroDeCosto();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Consulta con exito"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Error al Consultar Lista"));
    }
}

public UbicacionTecnicaDTO getUbicacionTecnicaDTO() {
    return ubicacionTecnicaDTO;
}

public void setUbicacionTecnicaDTO(UbicacionTecnicaDTO ubicacionTecnicaDTO) {
    this.ubicacionTecnicaDTO = ubicacionTecnicaDTO;
}

public List<UbicacionTecnicaDTO> getListaUbicacionTecnica() {
    return listaUbicacionTecnica;
}

public void setListaUbicacionTecnica(List<UbicacionTecnicaDTO> listaUbicacionTecnica) {
    this.listaUbicacionTecnica = listaUbicacionTecnica;
}

public IUbicacionTecnicaService getUbicacionTecnicaService() {
    return ubicacionTecnicaService;
}

public void setUbicacionTecnicaService(IUbicacionTecnicaService ubicacionTecnicaService) {
    this.ubicacionTecnicaService = ubicacionTecnicaService;
}

public UbicacionTecnicaDTO getSelectedUbicacionTecnica() {
    return selectedUbicacionTecnica;
}

public void setSelectedUbicacionTecnica(UbicacionTecnicaDTO selectedUbicacionTecnica) {
    this.selectedUbicacionTecnica = selectedUbicacionTecnica;
}
```

}

Advertencia:   Definiendo valor de atributo no serializable en ViewMap: (clave: sdiacMB, clase de valor: controlador.SistemaDeInventarioACManagedBean)
Grave:   javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /dirUbicTec.xhtml @62,100 value="": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:866)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1291)

Comment: Advertencia:   Definiendo valor de atributo no serializable en ViewMap: (clave: sdiacMB, clase de valor: controlador.SistemaDeInventarioACManagedBean)
Grave:   javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /dirUbicTec.xhtml @62,100 value="": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
 at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:866)

Comment: El controlador y la clase implementan Serializable?

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en el stack de tu excepción puedes ver:

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException:
```

lo cual viene de

`javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:866)`

La fase `updateModel` debe setear en el backing bean el valor luego de submiteado y validado y para poder hacerlo debe haber un `setter` definido para el atributo del bean (de lo contrario no tiene forma de escribir si el miembro es privado)

Cómo no publicas la totalidad de tu xhtml no es posible saber a que corresponde la linea 62 (si te fijas el stack ves que es allí donde se produce `PropertyNotWritableException`); pero  viendo tu modelo y el xhtml, es probable que alguno de los atributos de la clase `UbicacionTecnicaDTO` no tenga definido el `setter`

Verifica que hayas establecido getters y setters para:

-tipoLugar

-ubicacion

-denominacion

-idUbicacionTecnica